# Node's --inspect debugger not showing all source files

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

When I debug my script using `--inspect`, most of the sources show up, but many (seemingly arbitrarily) do not.

Is there any way to get my debugger to load all the source files, or has anyone ran into a similar problem?

Running node 9.1.1
Have tried reinstalling node.
Have tried clearing restoring defaults in the settings of chrome dev tools.
Have tried manually adding folder to workplace, on click nothing happens.